# pgadmin - ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bigint

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to import a CSV file via pgadmin dn it keeps throwing an error on the first line

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "﻿8668394"
```

I recognize the "" say it is is trying to import the integer as a string but I can't understand why this is the case.  When I open the CSV in notepad++ it doesn't show any quote marks or formating that might be causing this.  This is what I see in notepad++

```
8668394,Damoujia,China,Asia/Shanghai,36.54356,119.81326 CR LF
9123882,Shanwang,China,Asia/Shanghai,36.5454,118.711 CR LF
11969451,Katang Ailieke,China,Asia/Urumqi,38.15279,85.51784 CR LF
12110889,Wulong,China,Asia/Shanghai,29.32431,107.76056 CR LF
12324243,Yingqiu,China,Asia/Shanghai,36.52663,118.99285 CR LF
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: By loading an intentionally defective string, you can see that the quote marks are part of the error message framing, not part of the data being complained about.  The problem is likely some control character which notepad++ doesn't make clear.  Try a different tool, like `od`

Comment: @jjanes thank you for putting me on the right track.  The issue was actually the encoding being used was UTF8 BOM, which of course hides a Byte Order Mark at the start of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else facing a similar issue.  My problem was that the file was encoded using UTF8-BOM, in notepad++ select Encoding > UTF-8 and resave your file.  This will remove the hidden Byte Order Mark(BOM) at the start of the file and allow the import to work correctly.